# Mandrill SPF Error for Domain

Tags: dns, mandrill, spf

Attempting to setup my sending domain with Mandrill. I have successfully verified the domain and DKIM settings.

However, I am still getting the following SPF error:

> Your SPF record requires more than 10 DNS lookups to process. This
>   could be caused by including domains that require multiple lookups.
>   Try simplifying your SPF record by removing any unnecessary parts.

Here's what I currently have for my TXT record:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:bluehost.com include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all
```

Is the issue with my TXT record? Or could it be something else.

*Update: Needed to decrease my domain's DNS lookup count; solution in comments of answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep! The issue is with the TXT record (it's okay to have a matching SPF and TXT records, but Mandrill will only look at your TXT record to verify/validate sending domains so you want to make sure that one is correct).

Each part of the TXT record, `a`, `mx`, `ptr`, `include:bluehost.com`, and  `include:spf.mandrillapp.com`, count as one or more lookups, but the spec for SPF records (or in this case, TXT records that contain SPF information), limit you to 10 lookups total.

You can use a tool like this one to see which parts of the record have the most lookups: http://emailstuff.org/authentication (use the "Check a published SPF record" option) and maybe check out something like this to flatten the record: https://github.com/jsarenik/spf-tools.

Comment: Thanks. Could the fact that I'm checking mail for my domain via gmail (using POP3) be increasing my lookups?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The only thing that contributes to the number of lookups is what's in the TXT record. If I had to guess, the `include:bluehost.com` part is what's putting you over the limit (they appear to include several other services like Google in their SPF record), but you'd have to use an online validator to be sure where the most lookups actually are and remove some of them if you can.

Comment: I removed the "a", "mx", and "ptr" from my TXT and it decreased my lookup count < 10. Thanks for your help